# Javascript regex return true if custom pattern is 100% matched

Tags: javascript, regex

In vanilla Javascript I want to check a string.

```
const myRegex = /^\d+|#\d+/g;
console.log(`${myRegex.test("3#123#432#555")}`); // pattern is ok -> true
console.log(`${myRegex.test("3#123#432##555")}`); // two ## -> patter wrog -> but result is true (would like this to be false)
console.log(`${myRegex.test("3#123#432#55a5")}`); // a character in the string -> pattern wrong -> but result is true (should also be false)
```

I played around in https://regex101.com/r/tI1sOa/1/
I get a perfect match using this regex but I want it to return false when the pattern is altered.

Pattern definition should be: number#number#number#number#number (so first we have a number followed by #number, as many times as I want)

If the pattern is number### or #number or numberLetter#number or any other combination that does not respect the pattern should return false for the test.

How can I check this with regex? Why is the one I came up with not working as I expect it?

Thank you!

Comment: So ah, exactly how many of these `#numbers` you need for validation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^\d+|#\d+` means

- match one or more digits at the start of the string
- **or** match a `#` followed by one or more digits *anywhere* in the string.

In other words, the `^` is part of the first alternative, it doesn't apply to second one.

A pattern that fulfills your requirements would be:

```
^\d+(#\d+)+$
```

- match one or more digits a the start of the string followed by one or more sequences consisting of a `#` followed by one or more digits, till the end of the string

Comment: Thank you! This works and I have a better understanding of regex now.